# How can I sort a list based on other properties within the list

Tags: c#, linq, dapper

I want to order the list based on the order in which a class hierarchy is formed.

For example.

```
[ParentNode, ChildNode]
[A, B] //1st
[B, Y] 
[Y, Z] //last
```

I cannot sort by characters, i need to sort by parent vs child relationships.

```
[ParentNode, ChildNode]
[NULL,      IDS]
[EFL,       PEFL001]
[IDS,       EFL]
[PCMN010,   PCMN014]
[PEFL001,   PCMN010]
[PEFL001,   PCMN010]
```

In the example above, you can see some sample data, this sample data resembles the current queries return values.

Row(1) can be marked as the "starting" point since its ParentNode is NULL. The issue is that Row(2)(ChildNode) != Row(3)(ParentNode).   When running into duplicates it needs to be smart enough to stack them together (in no particular order)

Below you can see the expected results. Notice that row(n).ChildNode = row(n+1).ParentNode with the exception of duplicates when they stack.
I need to be able to either do this in LINQ or SQL

```
[ParentNode, ChildNode]
[NULL,      IDS]
[IDS,       EFL]
[EFL,       PEFL001]
[PEFL001,   PCMN010]
[PEFL001,   PCMN010]
[PCMN010,   PCMN014]
```

Comment: Can you also show the declaration of your data structures please. Are `ParentNode` and `ChildNode` properties within a class or elements within a collection?

Comment: The declaration comes from a database. 

list = connection.Query<Node>($"EXEC GetHierarchy '{id}'").ToList();

Thats the best i can supply

Comment: Well, then the list must be of type `List<Node>`. You could show us the `Node` class.

Comment: We cannot write code for unknown types. We have nothing we can work on. Please provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use either `IComparable` or `IComparer` and both have generics for type safety.
[IComparable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable-1?view=netframework-4.8)
[IComparer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icomparer-1?view=netframework-4.8)

The basic idea is you need to be able to compare to another of that type. The comparer returns a -1, 0, or 1 depending on which should be first. You could look at the objects children and make that determination in the comparison.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but its not an answer.

Comment: Actually it is. Perhaps you just don't understand how to implement.

Comment: "Whats 2 + 2?"  N_tro_P: "Use Math to figure out the answer", "Thanks but thats not what i was asking"

Comment: @AndrewMills,  This is how ordering of lists works in .Net. You should implement the IComparable if you want to sort. Then when you run "Sort" on the collection, it will use the implementation of IComparable on your objects. Perhaps you need to read the links provided or dig into more what "sorting" means. Making snide remarks only proves you do not understand what you are asking and put up a bad question. I was trying to help you, and yet you flame.